# "Light" serverless SQL engine with T-SQL language access

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to create integration tests for a program that will be connected to a SQL Server in production.

But I would like the unit tests to be shippable and loadable without the need for a running SQL Server...

- I am willing to write a stub to adapt to the alternating SQLServer / "Light SQL for tests"
- I would like to keep the existing T-SQL queries as they are. Not change a single dot in them.

Would you kindly suggest an option ?

Comment: strictly speaking, unit tests should not require an external system such as a database. If they do, they tend to be integration tests...

Comment: [SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) might something you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use advanced T-SQL features, SQL CE ought to be enough.

Comment: An integration test should be as close to the production environment as posible. SQL CE has quite a few differences...

Comment: I agree, this is not extra rigorous, but better than nothing.